# Como crear un ordenamiento burbuja para archivos binarios c++

Tags: c++

el problema es el siguiente, yo tengo un archivo binario con distintos usuarios, los cuales están ordenados por orden de ingreso al sistema, cada uno de los mismos tiene un número aleatorio, lo que quiero es ordenarlos de menor a mayor por ese número, no quiero que se ordenen en el archivo, si no que muestre en pantalla los nombres ingresados ordenados por el número random de menor a mayor, estoy perdido y no se como seguir, el poco código que hice no funcionó aunque no creo que esté mal encaminado, muchas gracias!

```
struct alumno
{
    char apellidoYNombre[50];
    char grado[50];
    char dojo[50];
    char sexo;
    char prom;
    char kata[50];
    char kumite[50];
    int rand;
    int edad;
};
void aleatorizar()
{
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("lista_alumnos.dat","rb");
    alumno a;
    cout << "\n\n\nIngrese si es Kata o Kumite: ";
    char kok[50];
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(kok);
    if(strcmp(kok,"Kata")==0 || strcmp(kok,"kata")==0)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese la categoría de Kata: ";
        char kata[50];
        int num;
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(kata);
        fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);
        srand(time(NULL));
        while(!feof(f)) // Con esto le doy un número random a cada integrante del sistema que cumpla con el Kata seleccionado
        {
            a.rand = rand() % 100;
            cout << a.rand << endl;
            cout << a.apellidoYNombre << endl;
            fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);
        }
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);
        fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);
        while(!feof(f)) // La idea es que acá este el método burbuja
        {
            num = rand();
            if(a.rand < num)
            {
                cout << a.apellidoYNombre << endl;
            }
            fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: y cual es el error que te da el codigo?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Es q no hay error, directamente no se que hacer jajajajaja, osea, le doy números random a cada alumno, ahora, como los ordeno para q los muestre en pantalla

Comment: pero tienes que decir por que no funciona en algun lugar estas trabado ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 A partir del segundo while(!feof) No funciona, xq no se como hacer un metodo burbuja con archivos binarios :D

Comment: en el bubble sort cada elemento "burbujea" hasta su posición final por medio de swaps/intercambios así que vas a necesitar un array/vector en memoria u otro archivo para ir guardando/recordando esos intercambios/swaps, el algoritmo termina ( la cosa está en orden ) cuando se recorren los items y ya no se producen swaps/intercambios. el algoritmo es el mismo independientemente de que los datos provengan de un archivo binario

Comment: ¿Seguro que la pregunta es [tag:c++]? Tiene toda la pinta de ser [tag:c].

Comment: @aloMalbarez Y como podría pasar los datos del archivo a un vector?? Esa la pensé tambien

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Sip, es C++, así me enseñaron a programar en la facultad jajajajja, creo q hay otra forma para utilizar archivos pero es la q me enseñaron ah

Answer (score 0):

Para poder hacer una ordenación (del tipo que sea) necesitas que tu colección de datos cumpla con al menos estas características.

1. Los elementos de la colección de datos deben poderse acceder en cualquier posición en cualquier momento (se conoce como [acceso aleatorio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/random_access_iterator)).
2. Los elementos de la colección de datos deben poder intercambiar posiciones dentro de la colección.
3. Los elementos de la colección de datos deben poder compararse entre sí para determinar su orden.

Para empezar, no veo que cumplas con los dos primeros puntos ya que no guardas la información en ninguna colección de datos; ni siquiera quieres que el orden dentro del archivo se vea alterado.

Por lo tanto, lo primero es crear esa colección:

```
using lista_alumnos = std::deque<alumno>;

lista_alumnos alumnos;
```

Una vez tienes la colección de datos, le añades elementos cada vez que los leas de archivo:

```
while(!feof(f))
{
    a.rand = rand() % 100;
    cout << a.rand << endl;
    cout << a.apellidoYNombre << endl;
    fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);

    alumnos.push_back(a);
}
```

Con los elementos ya leídos puedes proceder a ordenar con el algoritmo que creas conveniente:

```
for (auto u = alumnos.begin(), ue = (alumnos.end() - 1); u != ue; ++u)
    for (auto v = u + 1, ve = alumnos.end(); v != ve; ++v)
        if (u->rand > v->rand)
            std::swap(*u, *v);
```

Comment: Me salta un error en la primer línea "error: 'deque' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type|"

Comment: Una pregunta, podría crear un vector y darle los datos del archivo? Así sería mas sencillo, y no es que no puedan cambiar de posición, es q no me interesa eso, lo que me interesa es q aparezcan en pantalla en una posición diferente, pero si no se cambia en el archivo no me importa, creo q la solución más efectiva es pasar todo lo del archivo a un vector y hacer el método, pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: Muchas gracias compa, ya lo solucioné :D

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hice para solucionarlo fue lo siguiente, creé un vector al cual le fui dando los valores que me interesaba imprimir del archivo, luego, hice el típico método burbuja e imprimí los valores que quería.

```
void aleatorizar()
{

    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("lista_alumnos.dat","rb+");
    alumno a;
    cout << "\n\n\nIngrese si es Kata o Kumite: ";
    char kok[50];
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(kok);
    int i=0;
    alumno vec[100];
    if(strcmp(kok,"Kata")==0 || strcmp(kok,"kata")==0)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese la categoría de Kata: ";
        char kata[50];
        int num;
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(kata);
        srand(time(NULL));
        fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);
        while(!feof(f))
        {
            if(strcmp(kata,a.kata)==0)
            {
                a.rand=rand() %100;
                strcpy(vec[i].apellidoYNombre ,a.apellidoYNombre);
                strcpy(vec[i].dojo ,a.dojo);
                vec[i].rand = a.rand;
                i++;
            }
            else if(!feof(f) && strcmp(kata,a.kata)!=0)
            {
                cout << "La categoría ingresada no existe o está vacía" << endl;
            }
            fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);
        }
        alumno aux;
        for(int r=0;r<i;r++)
        {
            for(int j=r+1;j<i;j++)
            {
                if(vec[r].rand>vec[j].rand)
                {
                    strcpy(aux.apellidoYNombre, vec[r].apellidoYNombre);
                    strcpy(vec[r].apellidoYNombre, vec[j].apellidoYNombre);
                    strcpy(vec[j].apellidoYNombre, aux.apellidoYNombre);
                }
            }
        }
        for(int r=0; r<=i; r++)
        {
            cout << vec[r].apellidoYNombre << endl;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```